# Will a cast ever fail in C?

Tags: c, types, casting

Specifically, my question is, given this macro:

```
#define FAKE_VAL(type) ((type)0)
```

...is there any value of `type` (including structures, function pointers, etc.) where `FAKE_VAL(type)` will cause a compile-time error?

I'm asking because I have a macro that take a function pointer as an argument, and needs to find the size of its return value. I know the types and number of arguments the function pointer takes, so I'm planning to write something like:

```
sizeof(fptr(FAKE_VAL(arg_type_1), FAKE_VAL(arg_type_2)))
```

`arg_type_1` and `2` could be literally anything.

Comment: I suppose we're excluding values like `;;;` or `2` for `type`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast an int to an array type, so

```
FAKE_VAL(int[5]);
```

will fail. [Try it!](http://ideone.com/AdRrU5)

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is.

`struct fred` (i.e. not a pointer) - how do you convert 0 (scalar type) to a struct (non scalar type)?
Any literal value `FAKE_VAL("hi")` gives `(("hi")0)` - what does that mean?

Comment: In this particular case, the argument of FAKE_VAL is assumed to be a type. See user2327112's comment.

Comment: `struct fred` is a type. Perhaps you mean a scalar type?

Comment: @John3136: `"hi"` isn't a type, so your other example doesn't work. `struct fred` fits the conditions and breaks the cast, though, especially if `struct fred` is an incomplete type.

Comment: `struct fred` being incomplete is irrelevant - you can't cast scalar (0) to non scalar (struct or array)

Comment: @John3136: Yeah, but if it's incomplete, it also breaks `((struct fred){0})`.

Answer (score 0):

To give it a more systematic answer. In C cast are only allowed for arithmetic and pointer types. So anything that is a `struct`, `union` or array type would lead to a compile time error.

Answer (score -1):

typecast is used to inform the compiler that the programmer has already considered the side effects of using the variable in a different way than it was declared as. This causes the compiler to switch off its checks. So with typecasts you wont get warnings/errors. 
Yeah. it does type conversion of any type to the typecasted one. My bad.
But this can cause segmentation faults/errors when the program is actually run.

Comment: Surely it does more than 'switch off type checks'.

Comment: @user2864740 `2 == (int)2.7;` - Undoubtedly.